# Return true when detect event response

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteers. I have created a `page.on('response')` that is listening that is listening for requests.

I have a loop that takes care of scrolling. How can I detect if scrolling raises the 'response' event?
I was thinking of returning a boolean from the event, but how could I capture it?

```
        page.on('response', (response) => {
            if (response.url().indexOf('page') >= 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        while(items.length < howMuchItems) {
            await page.evaluate((sel) => {
                window.scrollBy(0, document.scrollingElement.querySelector(sel).scrollHeight);
            }, selectors.CONTAINER_SCROLLED);

            // Detect if exists event response
            // If doesn´t exist => break loop

            items= await page.$$(selectors.ITEM);
        }
```

Comment: try with node.js eventEmitter. [Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your program logic, but generally you must create like this code

```
        const waitForNewItems = () => 
          new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
           page.once('response', (response) => {
            if (response.url().indexOf('page') >= 0) {
                return resolve(true);
            } else {
                return resolve(false);
            }
           });

        while(items.length < howMuchItems) {
            await page.evaluate((sel) => {
                window.scrollBy(0, document.scrollingElement.querySelector(sel).scrollHeight);
            }, selectors.CONTAINER_SCROLLED);

            // Detect if exists event response
            // If doesn´t exist => break loop

            const bool = await waitForNewItems();
            if (!bool) break;

            items= await page.$$(selectors.ITEM);
        }
```